# Сортировка словаря в списке, что происходит под "капотом" lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

Всем привет, не смог разобраться, как написать функцию, которая заменит lambda-функцию. Есть list, содержащий в себе dict, который необходимо отсортировать. Сделал это через lambda-функцию, только это не pythonic way. Будьте так добры, покажите пример или ссылочку на RTFM.

> В отличие от лямбда функций в других языках, где они добавляют функциональность, лямбды в Python являются лишь сокращенной записью, если вы слишком ленивы, чтобы определить функцию. ([Source](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-lambda-expressions-contain-statements))

```
products = [
           {"name": "meat", "price": 15},
           {"name": "pen", "price": 5},
           {"name": "whiteboard", "price": 170}
           ]

products.sort(key=lambda i: i["price"])
```

Сам пробовал работать со словарями как с элементами массива и ни к чему не пришёл. Видел на сайте решение пузырьковой сортировкой. Но что происходит именно с lambda?

```
#Мой не правильный вариант
for i in data:
     products.sort(key=sor(i))


def sor(i):
    return i["price"]
```

Почему если следующие функции равнозначны, мой вариант переписать лямбду не работает.

```
def identity(x):
    return x

lambda x: x
```

Comment: `def sor(i): return i["price"]` и потом просто `products.sort(key=sor)`

Comment: Почему (key=sor)? без параметра()

Comment: @Shellait потому что здесь нужно не вызывать функцию, а передать непосредственно объект функции без всяких вызовов. Дальше функция sort сама будет вызывать эту функцию и передавать все нужные параметры так же как и в лямбду

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sor(i):
    return i["price"]
```

и потом просто `products.sort(key=sor)` – andreymal